# Using swiper js in svelte

Tags: svelte, swiper.js

Hi guys I am trying to use swiper js and the swipe doesn't work,

Here is my code structure:

```
<Swiper
    spaceBetween={0}
    slidesPerView={1}
    >
        {#each projects as project, i}
            <SwiperSlide>
                // my slides code
            </SwiperSlide>
        {/each}
</Swiper>
```

In my editor I get this error on the swiper element

```
Element does not support attributes because type definitions are missing for this Svelte Component or element cannot be used as such.

Underlying error:
JSX element class does not support attributes because it does not have a '$$prop_def' property.
```

and this error on the SwiperSlide element

```
Type definitions are missing for this Svelte Component. It needs a class definition with at least the property '$$prop_def' which should contain a map of input property definitions.
Example:
  class ComponentName { $$prop_def: { propertyName: string; } }
If you are using Svelte 3.31+, use SvelteComponentTyped:
  import type { SvelteComponentTyped } from "svelte";
  class ComponentName extends SvelteComponentTyped<{propertyName: string;}> {}

Underlying error:
'SwiperSlide' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its instance type 'Swiper' is not a valid JSX element.
    Property '$$prop_def' is missing in type 'Swiper' but required in type 'ElementClass'.
```

I understand this error may have something to do with typescript but I don't think I am using typescript, also it compiles and I can see it in the browser but the swipe doesn't work

Comment: I have confirmed those errors have nothing to do with the problem I am facing, I have all the pagination and buttons but can't get it to swipe

Answer (score 0):

Here how i did it in my project:

```
<script lang="ts">
// Import Swiper Svelte components
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/svelte';

// Import Swiper styles for GAmeCard in GameSection (To load once)
import 'swiper/css';

import Card from "../Card/Card.svelte"

</script>

<Swiper>
  <SwiperSlide>
    <Card />
  </SwiperSlide>
  <SwiperSlide>
     <Card />
  </SwiperSlide>
</Swiper>
```